# Octave suddenly running scripts slowly after crash

Tags: octave

I am running Octave 4.4.1 x64 on a Dell Precision 7520 (Core i7-7820HQ @ 2.9 GHz, 16 GB RAM) with Windows 10 Pro, which I installed from the binary provided on the GNU FTP site. I have been running a simple physical model that consists of solving a non-stiff non-linear ODE, using a explicit numerical scheme in a for loop. I've been running the model multiple times while changing model parameters in order to fit the solution to some test data I have. The script takes just a couple seconds to run, so it was expedient to run it multiple times to heuristically estimate the model parameter values.

Octave is very buggy on my PC, and crashes often. Usually I just restart it and carry on. Yesterday after a crash, I reopened Octave and tried to run the model again. At first I thought it was hung up, but it turns out the model execution time had just increased by an order of magnitude or more. I checked some other data processing scripts that I've created in the past that used to run very quickly, and they are also now running very slowly, to the point where they are too slow to be useable.

I can run my model in MATLAB and it still takes just a second or so. I used 'profile' in Octave to see where the hang-up might be, and the sum of all the function executions is less than a second, whereas the difference between the tic and toc at the beginning and end of the file is ~25 s.

I've reinstalled Octave, tried different versions of the installer, and I'm at a bit of a loss now. I've tried searching for others' experience with similar problems and haven't come up with anything. Any advice or input would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what exact situation do you call "a crash?" Do you see a warning or error message and can you reproduce it?

Comment: Also please check anti virus scanners and if the system is swapping

Comment: Hi Andy, when I say crash I mean that Octave crashes and exits. From looking at the system log, it has something to do with 'ntdll.dll'. I have checked and disabled anti-virus scanning.

Comment: Update: in my question I said that I had tried different versions of Octave. What I should have said was that I tried different installers of Octave v4.4.1 (w64, w32, w64 w/ 64-bit LA). I am able to run my scripts with normal performance if I install Octave v4.4.0 or v4.2.2. This is very puzzling as this was a sudden change after using v4.4.1 for several months. I have since tried reinstalling v4.4.1 but the problem persists.

Comment: is there an octave_workspace file from the crash that may be loading up whenever you launch octave by any chance? (it may be a hidden one)

Comment: @E.Kastanis hi. Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou. Hi, I never did resolve this issue with v4.4.1. At the time I reverted to using v4.4.0, and since then have upgraded to v5.2.0 and v6.1.0 on the same machine without any issues. While troubleshooting I did reinstall v4.4.1 several times and the issue came back each time, which was perplexing after using that version for several months without issue. At any rate newer versions of Octave haven't given me the same trouble, and run much more stably on this PC than v4.x releases did.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I am having the same problem. When I run octave in batch mode through my python script by using the oct2py library it takes ages to compile. However, the same script doesn't even take a minute to compute in my Matlab...

Comment: @Wallflower "runs faster on matlab" aside, this does not sound like the same issue _at all_. (presumably you're not even using Octave v4.4.1 specifically, otherwise you could have simply updated octave like the user above). And also, `oct2py` is an entirely different beast to octave, let alone matlab. At best you should be comparing a python-to-octave interface against a python-to-matlab interface. In any case, you're probably better off asking a standalone question instead.