# Octave runs more slowly after force quit

Tags: performance, crash, octave

I am running Octave 6.2.0. I have had to force quit the software after it became unresponsive while I moved its window across monitors, and since then any code I run takes much longer than it used to.

I run the same script with profile on on the "newly" slow computer and another laptop. Dlmread and fprintf make up for over 99% of execution time for the script, so I just compared times for those two functions.

Test 1: Octave 6.2.0 (after crash) on Dell Precision 3640 (Core i7-10700 @ 2.9 GHz, 64 GB RAM) with Windows 10 Pro, from SSD.

Test 2: Octave 6.2.0 (after crash) on Dell Precision 3640 (Core i7-10700 @ 2.9 GHz, 64 GB RAM) with Windows 10 Pro, from HDD.

Test 3: Octave 5.2.0 (for comparison) on Dell Inspiron 5570 (Core i7-8550U @ 1.8 GHz, 32 GB RAM) with Windows 10 Pro, from HDD.

```
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|        | dlmread time (s) | fprintf time (s) | Total script time (s) |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| Test 1 | 138              | 249              | 388                   |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| Test 2 | 138              | 278              | 417                   |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| Test 3 | 48               | 45               | 93                    |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, clearing cache and preferences, installing an older version of Octave, but nothing seems to solve the problem.

Any idea of what may have gone wrong and anything else I could do to troubleshoot?

A similar issue is described in this post, but no solution was posted in that case: [Octave suddenly running scripts slowly after crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729971/octave-suddenly-running-scripts-slowly-after-crash).

Comment: If downgrading (i.e. using a different program) still has your I/O running so slowly, this is likely not Octave but your OS or something else. Have you rebooted? Have you copied your file to a new location and used that?

Comment: I have rebooted a few times in the process and tried running from different folders and different hard drives, but no luck. I'm wondering whether there's a chance of solving the issue by getting rid of some runaway system file or whether I have to start thinking about a clean Windows restore.

Comment: @M.Inve I made a comment on the post you linked to, about an octave workspace file. Have you checked for that?

Comment: Also, how large is your dataset / do you write lots of data on file? It may be a case that when you crashed, you've created a situation where the harddisk was left in an invalid state, and needs checking / fixing / defragging, etc? Or there is a large unused file on your harddisk (e.g. an [octave-workspace dumpfile](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Saving-Data-on-Unexpected-Exits.html#Saving-Data-on-Unexpected-Exits)?) that is causing the harddisk to have to make massive jumps to collect data around it.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I have searched and deleted all files named *octave*+something in between reinstalls, including hidden files, but no change. Files are up to 2GB, but there's plenty more space on disk. I'll try some diagnostic on the disk and get back.